# Python 2.6 - How to obtain the o'clock-time from timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

I'm working with a cx_Oracle database with records having each `timestamp` and `value` columns. I need to elaborate avg, or min, or sum or other aggregate functions(according to a config file) for records stored every hour(24 slots per day: 00-01, 01-02... 23-00). Every table starts with different timestamp, maybe ten years ago or yesterday, so I should consider to aggregate records starting from the hour of first timestamp. Supposing the first timestamp is 14h:43m:20s, this record is to be stored in 14-15 slot. The question is what is the best way to calculate timestamp corresponding to 14:00 o'clock of that timestamp? Then i thought to proceed by one hour step using `timedelta + 1h` arithmetic and do what i need. Anyway I accept any advice if this is not the best way to proceed.

Comment: Should you not do the grouping and aggregation in SQL rather than in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more on SQL rather than python. This is how I get the average (or other aggregates) via SQL.

```
select avg(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM <timestamp>)) as avg_hrs, 
min(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM <timestamp>)) as min_hrs, 
sum(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM <timestamp>)) as sum_hrs
from <table>;
```

Sum does not make sense but I leave it to you to find it usefulness.
Here is another query for counts. Hope this helps.

```
select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM <timestamp>) as hrs, count(*) as cnt
from <table>
group by EXTRACT(HOUR FROM <timestamp>)
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, i would like to work by SQL, but the problem is that table has another column `name` that I need to group by, and then order by `timestamp`. I mean `...ORDER BY name, timestamp`, and I must work on all records from a specific `name` ordered by `timestamp`, and then group them with the aggregate function. So, i cannot group only by timestamp because of the possibility they belong to different `name` values. I hope it's clear what I'm saying.

Comment: I'm trying with this `select avg(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM 1435047532)) as hour` but returns this error:  _invalid extract field for extract source_  Where am I wrong?

Comment: 1435047532 is not a timestamp but a value of a data with type timestamp. So if you get the HOUR value from it, it will not make sense since is it not a date timestamp type of data.  Pls give me a sample data for your table with their column names and what you want to achieve (like group by this column then avg this column..etc)

Comment: Thanks, I try to explain. Suppose columns are _time_, _host_, _value_. What i need are results order by _host_ before and then by timestamp for each host separately. Then, talking of one single host separately, I must group result with one hour step and by aggragate function(e.g. AVG, SUM...). Record resulting from the aggregation of results between 14:00 and 14:59:59 will must have a timestamp with the same date but representing the hour with 0 minutes and 0 seconds(e.g. 14:00:00). Those ones between 15:00 and 15:59:59 the timestamp ending with15:00:00, and so on. This for each different host